# Okta Sign-In Widget - Login Credentials Sent as Clear Text, already on SSL

Tags: asp.net, ssl, model-view-controller, okta

We have been using `Okta` in one of our applications running on `ASP.Net MVC` and are using `Okta` Sign-In Widget.

We did a security audit on our application and it pointed out a vulnerability saying, `Login Credentials Sent as Clear Text`.

Upon looking into the network activity, I realised that it does in fact send credentials as clear text.

Our site is already on `SSL` but we want the credentials to be encrypted as well.

Can someone please guide how we can fix these with the `Okta` Sign-In Widget?

Answer (score 0):

Login credentials **are** encrypted in transit using TLS (TLS 1.0+ using AES 256-bit encryption).